# Should we improve span code links highlighting?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, code, formatting

This is an inline span of preformatted text:

[image]

Let's put a link on it:

[image]

Nothing changes.
Should we learn from Stack Overflow?

[image]

Comment: Markdown inside of formatted text can be tricky, but this has always bugged me too.

Comment: From MSE in days of yore: [Problem with double backticks for marking inline code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77349/213963),